# How can I disable a custom toolbar button in CKEditor 5?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I implemented a version of the image insert *Simple Plugin* example from [CKEditor 5's framework docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/creating-simple-plugin.html).

But the example doesn't cover how to disable the item when the editor's `isReadOnly` property is set (like it does by default for all the standard buttons). I [found docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_button_buttonview-ButtonView.html) for an `isEnabled` prop as well as a `bind` method for `ButtonView`, but it quotes examples using a `command` item, rather than a `view` item. Problem is, the *Simple Plugin* example doesn't create a command to bind to.

So question is whether I need to create a command, or if there is some other way to make the view item's state sensitive to the readonly state of the editor instance.

Thanks, and my apologies if I've left out any needed context (new to posting here on SO). Feedback is welcome (and I know y'all will whip me into shape).

Answer (score 4):

D'oh, I think I figured it out:

`view.bind('isEnabled').to(editor, 'isReadOnly', isReadOnly => !isReadOnly);`

Just needed to bind to the observable property of the editor. Seems to be working as I desired/expected.